# How to check null values in JSON property in stream analytics?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I am Passing the following Json input from Eventhub to Stream Analytics.

```
{"meter_totalcycleenergy":null,"Test2": 20}, {"meter_totalcycleenergy":40,"Test2":20}
```

But the job is failing stating the error.

> Encountered error trying to write 1 event(s): Cannot convert from property 'meter_totalcycleenergy' of type 'System.String' to column 'meter_totalcycleenergy' of type 'System.Single'.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLi1H.png)
How to handle such conditions.

I think Json nulls are not exactly SQL NULLs, so what would be the proper way to check for null values in a query?

Datatype of meter_totalcycleenergy is float in my database.

Comment: Adding a IS NOT NULL will works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is not null`. For eg:

```
select *
from input
where meter_totalcycleenergy is not null
```